# Prove that every irrational numbers can be approximated by rational numbers.

Tags: analysis, soft-question

> Prove that every irrational numbers can be approximated by rational numbers.

How can I do it?
Ok, I admit. I heard it, I thought it is to be true. 
And I was a kid. Now I when I think about it, I really do not know - what to think of it.

It is highly provable that for every $x < y \in \mathbb{Q}$ there exists $g \in  \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $ x < g < y$.
But how does this even remotely relate to what the theorem is all about?

## Edit

The way people **proved** it then ( kid ages )  was circular reasoning at best.
Take any base expansion of a real number:-
$$
g_b := \sum b^r d_r 
$$ and now we can obviously cut off the tail.
But wait. Who gave us the right to do so? Nobody! Because it implicitly assumes that the we can arbitrarily approximate any number! 
So, obviously what I was taught is a lie. 
Please help.

About *** reals can be written as decimal expansions***
Problem with that argument is that it is an axiom.
Axiomatically, the system is as follows:-

1. Integers : Result of Von Nuemmann numbering or Peano - whatever.
2. Rationals : Given integers - the real result of division.
3. Algebraic Numbers : Given finite polynomials, their real roots.
4. Algebraic irrationals : What does not belong to 2 but belong to 3
5. Whatever remains : we can *possibly* create from infinite expansion of polynomial equation - but we know that won't *only* work .

## Edit 2

I think I have found out how.
We can always cut the real line $[0,1]$ into $I_0,I_1,...,I_{b-1}$ 'b' different slices.
$$
S = \{  (0,1/b] , (1/b,2/b],...  \}
$$
As $g$ is irrational, it has to be within one of them.
That would mean that $g \in ( i/b , (i+1)/b ) $.
That would mean we choose the first digit of the base b expansion, using i.
Now, we can again divide the Interval $I_i$ by same construction.
That would give us the next digit in base b.
As the intervals are getting reduced by $1/b$, we can approximate the left and right side of $g$ arbitrarily. And that shows why base b expansion is possible for any real number.
Now that is the same Cauchy sequence ( of of many ) that Yoni was saying.

Thank you all folks!

Comment: It would expect something like this: Given an irrational numbe $w$, then for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exist rational numbers $r, s$ with $r < w < s$ and $s - r \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: How is that possible? That is the question. :(

Comment: If you assume that the decimal expansion of real numbers is well defined, you can chop off the irrational at the $n$th spot after the decimal point and use that as your rational number. Then the (absolute value of the) difference will be less than $1/10^{n}$. Since $1/10^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, you're done.

Comment: Indeed, but that is why I have added that edit. I thought about it, it is not reasonable at all. :(

Comment: No trickery is going on in the termination of the decimal expansion - when you cut off the tail, you get a perfectly good rational number; you don't need anyone to give you "the right to do so." If you don't like the decimal expansion result (which isn't circular if you accept that reals can be written as decimal expansions), how are you defining the irrationals/reals? Essentially every [definition of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) [the reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) constructs them as things that can be approximated arbitrarily well by rationals.

Comment: ***reals can be written as decimal expansions*** is the problem.

Comment: How are you defining real numbers in the first place ?

Comment: I, being the king of everything that is and will ever be, endow you, Noga of StackExchange the right to cut off the tail of an infinite decimal expansion. From this day forth, you shall be known as **Noga Tailcutter**.

Comment: Thank you! But I was always cutting the tail, now I got the authority! I really do not know whose authority anyways!

Comment: If asked how to do it: It seems continued fractions do the job. See [Diophantine Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) and [Continued Fractions - Rational Approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your edit, it is circular but not in a way you imagined. Why does a real number have an infinite base expansion? What is a real number anyway?

One way to define real numbers is as a metric completion of the rationals. That is, take any Cauchy sequence of rationals that does not converge. This Cauchy sequence defines a new number, which is irrational. Furthermore, two Cauchy sequences define the same number if the sequence of their differences tends to zero.

This definition justifies talking about infinite base expansions in the first place, and it also immediately follows from the definition that if $x$ has a base expansion $x = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} d_r b^r$, then $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^R d_r b^r = x.$$

Comment: that does *not* converge ?

Comment: He meant does not converge *inside* $\mathbb{Q}$. Still a problem - because it does show that from every incomplete Cauchy Converging sequence I can create an irrational number. It does not show that the correspondence is 1-1 onto.

Comment: It isn't 1-1, as I wrote: "Two Cauchy sequences define the same number if the sequence of their differences tends to zero." But you don't really need it to be 1-1, just for every real number to have one (at least) Cauchy sequence of rationals converging to it (that is, it needs to be onto). And why is it onto? Well - it is simply the definition of irrational numbers (one possible definition; there are others).

Comment: If you want to split hairs, it doesn't mean that reals can be approximated by rational, since with this definition they don't live in the same set. You still have to talk about the identification of $ℚ$ with a certain dense set of $ℝ$.

Comment: A metric space is automatically dense in its completion...

Answer (score 11):

To make rigorous proofs, we first need a rigorous definition. The usual definition of the real numbers are that they form a *complete ordered field*. In fact, it is the *only* complete ordered field (up to isomorphism).

One of the things you can prove is that the real numbers satisfy the Archimedean axiom: for every real number $r$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $n > r$.

We can use this to solve your particular problem: if we want to find a rational number $q$ such that $|q - r| < \epsilon$, then we can

- choose $n$ to be a natural number such that $n > 1/\epsilon$.
- choose $m = \lfloor rn \rfloor$
- choose $q = m/n$

and you can compute

$$ |q-r| = \left| \frac{m}{n} - r \right| = \frac{1}{n} |m - nr|  < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon $$

as desired. If you pay attention to details, you might wonder why $m$ is well-defined: if $r>0$ we can use the Archimedean axiom again to show there is a natural number $t > rn$, and then we can use induction to show that there must be a *largest* integer amongst the set of integers less than or equal to $rn$. (a similar argument works for $r<0$)

A more direct proof form the usual form of completeness is to consider the set $S$ of all rational numbers less than $r$: one can argue that $r$ must be the *least upper bound* of $S$, which in turn implies that $S$ must have elements arbitrarily close to $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an irrational number $x$. We can come up with the following function $f$ (where $b$ is the base used, usually obviously $10$)
$$f(x,n)=\frac{\left \lfloor b^nx \right \rfloor}{b^n}$$
As $n$ gets bigger, the rational number $f(x,n) $ starts to approximate $x$ better.
For example, to approximate $\pi$ in base-$10$ we can choose $n=3$ and get:
$$f(\pi , 3)=\frac{\left \lfloor 10^3\pi \right \rfloor}{10^3}=\frac{3141}{1000}=3.141$$
This whole thing of course pressuposes that any real number can be represented as an infinite string of digits of base-$b$ with a point somewhere inbetween, but that's a different story...